# FPDF not working properly in some browsers

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a php file which creates a PDF using FPDF. My php file does that after reading a few $_POST values, which "determine" what to display. The PDF is a single page, only containing simple text via Cell() and a few PNG images.

The PDF shows different behaviour accross browsers. I didn't find any information regarding this in the documentation. I found the following test-results:

1. Chrome (win)

   - Display: ok
   - Download: empty file
2. Firefox (win)

   - Display: keeps on loading
   - Download: empty file
3. Firefox (mac)

   - Display: keeps on loading
   - Download: ok
4. Safari (mac)

   - Display: ok
   - Download: ok

In the above, I mean with download: "Save file as" from the display-view, to distinguish from forced download via Output('foo.pdf', D). The latter is showing inconsistent results too.

What can cause my problems? Which steps can I take to debug any further?

Comment: What FPDF version are you using? Could you check if any output compression in your php environment is turned on?

Comment: FPDF v 1.7. PHP v. 5.5.23. Zlib is installed, but zlib.output_compression = Off. My knowledge to interpret phpinfo() is quite basic - if there are any specific entries I should look at I'd be happy to do so. In the FPDF.php file I have also tried setting $this->SetCompression(true); to 'false', with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After persistent digging, I found the cause for all trouble:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,13,' ',0,1);
```

So writing cells containing a space only seems to be not allowed. Instead, you can write

```
$pdf->Cell(0,13,'',0,1);
```

without problems.

**Edit:** I made the mistake to call Cell() before the first SetFont(). If you have set SetFont() first, a space in Cell() IS allowed. My bad :)