# $pdf->output("reports/SalesReport.pdf", "F"); Not Working on mac

Tags: fpdf

I have the same code which I am using to save the sales report as a pdf before sending it to a client's email address. The code works perfectly well on windows but has failed on mac. It doesn't create the SalesReport.pdf file

$pdf->output("reports/SalesReport.pdf", "F");

Comment: You said it's failed but you haven't described how it fails. Is the file just not created? Is the exact path the same as it is on Windows (including upper/lower case in the path name)? Is it created but missing some information? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Is this a browser issue? Not sure why it would fail on Mac and not Win.

Comment: I have a windows Machine and a Mac book both running Xampp. When I run the program on the windows machine, it works just fine, However, It doesn't respond that well on a MAC

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a cell definition in your code containing just space char?

```
$pdf->Cell(0,13,' ',0,1);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699270/fpdf-not-working-properly-in-some-browsers) stackoverflow article.

Roughly it says a cell with space (like above) not allowed unless you set the font with `SetFont()` function before.